# Decode() function query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, decode, embedded-sql, oracle-pro-c

Can we use a select query in embedded sql (Pro*C) as the first argument in a `Decode()` function.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that?  Is there no criteria you can use to join on?

Comment: Yes there are criterions however they are too expensive

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about embedded sql, but I guess it should work:

```
SELECT DECODE( ( SELECT 1 FROM dual ), 1, 'Yes', 'No' ) FROM dual

Yes
```

You need to put the `SELECT` in brackets.

Comment: I have edited the question, my intention is to use this in ProC (Embedded sql in C)

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: There's a lot of modern SQL constructs (eg introduced since 8.0) the precompilers can't use directly. You can use dynamic SQL or hide the SQL in a view.